# How to copy variable range vba

Tags: vba

My table contains variable number of rows and three columns (A:C) that I am interested in

```
    A   B   C  D
1  xx  xx  xx  xxx
2  ....
3  ....
4  ...
```

I need to copy from `WorkSheet1` to `WorkSheet2`

```
ws2.Range("A1").Value = ws1.Range("A1:C4").Value
```

The problem is that I do not want to hardcode `C4` , because it can be `C5` or   `C20` . How can I account for possible variable number of rows.

---

PS : I cannot use `Range("A1").CurrentRegion` because this will select more columns than needed, i.e. column `D` values will also get selected. Although it will select the correct number of rows

Comment: Will any rows below the chosen last row contain data?

Comment: Is your table a ListObject? If so, this is super easy. If not, you need some VBA to determine where the table "ends", which can be a little more difficult depending on the layout of your worksheet.

Comment: You might not have stumbled on [THIS](http://www.siddharthrout.com/2012/10/02/find-last-row-in-an-excel-sheetvbavb-net/) so give it a try?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is more than one solution to most problems, but since `CurrentRegion` method returns the right number of rows (but the wrong number of columns), you could do something like this assuming you always need THREE columns.

```
Dim rng as Range
Set rng = ws1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Resize(,3)

ws2.Range(rng.Address).Value = rng.Value
```

Comment: once you start using `Resize` and `Offset` your world will never be the same :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm making an assumption that the last row in D will be equal to or less than the last row of A:C.  I'm also assuming that the last row is determined by the last row that contains data.

```
Sub CopyColumnAtoC()
    Dim lastRow As Long

    lastRow = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1:C" & lastRow).Copy

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Range("A1:C" & lastRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End Sub
```

Comment: Typo (A2:C...) should be A1. Also, you can avoid actively using the `.Copy` method to copy/paste values, per OP's method of assigning the range's `.Value`.  Cheers!

Comment: @David Thanks for pointing out the typo.  I explicitly used the copy and paste as a safe guard in case my assumption about column D being longer were wrong.  If Column D is longer, then the corresponding rows of A:C could possibly contain `#N/A`

Answer (score 1):

You can specify just columns in a range. So

```
Sheet2.Range(Sheet1.Range("A:C").Address).Value = Sheet1.Range("A:C").Value
```

will copy columns A through C regardless of the rows in each column, *i.e.* if Column A has 8 rows, B has 6, and C has 11 it will still work.